# How to fix "Process exited before completing request" in Python Requests?

Tags: python-2.7, python-requests, postman

I am trying to replicate the successful POST operation performed using Postman in Python. My code is something like this:

```
import requests

url = "https://api.appx.com/v1/gen_ticket"

headers = {
    'authorizationtoken': "Bearer " + access_token,
    'x-api-key': "ddQk4mlTAl5cUj0N7omg4457jXuYlH25kOdvJoeJN3",
    'catalogitem': "eb29189cd00576b00dd3cf5951d96197d",
    'Content-Type': "application/json",
    }

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

but when i run this, i keep getting the following error (**This is working properly when using Postman but not in Python code)**.

```
{"errorMessage":"RequestId: af75334a-f955-11e8-b2e7-17baf7f53f31 Process exited before completing request"}
```

Can someone please suggest how to fix this?

One more thing to above is, i am passing a JSON file in Postman body section (how can i use the same in python code as well?)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try change `authorizationtoken` to `Authorization`

```
import requests

url = "https://api.appx.com/v1/gen_ticket"

headers = {
    'Authorization': "Bearer " + access_token,
    'x-api-key': "ddQk4mlTAl5cUj0N7omg4457jXuYlH25kOdvJoeJN3",
    'catalogitem': "eb29189cd00576b00dd3cf5951d96197d",
    'Content-Type': "application/json",
    }

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

Comment: It says: "errorMessage": "401 Authorization Failed." now.

Comment: maybe it mean content of Authorization is not valid